# IBM ThinkCenter doesn't power up

Tags: power-supply, troubleshooting, power, thinkcentre

My old ThinkCenter M-8143 doesn't boot. When I press the power button nothing happens. It's a brand new power supply, so can't be an issue with the PSU.

*If I remove the 4-pin CPU power connector and just leave the 24-pin ATX connector (http://www.legitreviews.com/images/reviews/418/gigabyte_ds3_labeled.jpg) and I plug in the power cable, CPU fan starts spinning. But it doesn't do so with both the connectors plugged in.

*There are 4 wires (2 yellow, 2 black) coming out of the power button switch and I tried shorting either of yellow-black wire pair; but nothing happens and it's still dead.

What could I do to get it working?

Comment: "It's a brand new power supply, so can't be an issue with the PSU." Not true. It could be broken on arrival. Test it with another PSU or test the PSU with another system to make sure you have a working one.

Comment: @Hennes Yet the fan starts up.

Comment: A PSU for a computer provides more than a single power. It has dedicated lines for +3.3 volt, +5 volt, +12 volt. Not all of those might work. (Note that I am not saying it is broken, just that the assumption that it is guaranteed working is not true).

Comment: Why'd you replace the PSU in the first place?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Good question. This will give the actual background of the problem

Answer (score 0):

You said

> *If I remove the 4-pin CPU power connector and just leave the 24-pin ATX connector (http://www.legitreviews.com/images/reviews/418/gigabyte_ds3_labeled.jpg) and if I plug in the power cable, CPU fan starts spinning. But it doesn't so with both the connectors plugged in.

When you said this I agreed with your statement that it wasn't the power-supply. Instead I believe it is the CPU. You see if your using a modern power-supply it won't give power to the board unless the board meets some requirements. This is a very logical process because if the board is broken and you apply power it might (will) damage the things attached. My suspicion is that either the CPU or the 4-pin connector is unhappy. When you said the fan starts up with it unplugged it was somewhat of a give away.